# how to configure Eclipse Quick Fix for misspelled words?

Tags: eclipse

How do i configure Eclipse's quick fix for misspelled words? There was an option to "add [word] to dictionary" but i somehow managed to disable this option. Where can i make it available again?

Comment: Have you looked under Spelling in Preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open

> {workspace_location}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs

- Delete the following preference (or set the value to false)

> do_not_ask_to_install_user_dictionary=true